# How to add publisher for setup

Tags: inno-setup

When we create a install program and we run it under windows 7 or vista , we see a Unknown for publisher in User Account control  info , how we can change it ?

Comment: I think that the real question is "How to *sign* your installer/application?"

Comment: First I didn't understand what you meant, because you said "User ACCESS control info". Now I understand that you was talking about User Account Control (UAC).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using InnoSetup 5.2 or later, there is a signtool parameter you can add to your script.
Here's an excerpt from the InnoSetup documentation:

> [Setup]: SignTool
>   Valid values:  A name followed by zero
>   or more parameters, space separated
>
> Description: Specifies the name and
>   parameters of the Sign Tool to be used
>   to digitally sign Setup (and Uninstall
>   if SignedUninstaller is set to yes).
>   When Setup has a valid digital
>   signature, users will not see an
>   "unidentified program" warning when
>   launching it.
>
> The specified Sign Tool name and its
>   command have to be defined in the
>   compiler IDE (via the Tools |
>   Configure Sign Tools... menu) or on
>   the compiler command line (via the
>   "/S" parameter), else an error will
>   occur.
>
> The following special sequences may be
>   used in Sign Tool parameters and
>   commands:
>
> $f, replaced by the quoted file name
>   of the file to be signed.
>
> $p, replaced by the Sign Tool
>   parameters.
>
> $q, replaced by a quote, usefull for
>   defining a Sign Tool which contains
>   quotes from the command line.

Comment: Documentation with examples [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool)